# cordova angularjs force app to pause waiting on user permission

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, callback, user-permissions

I am using cordova-firebase-plugin, one of the requirements on iOS for push notifications is to grant permissions, the problem is that using cordova-firebase-plugin `grantPermission` does not have a proper callback for success/error - thus when grantPermission is called it pops the permission request up to the user but in the background the app keeps loading.

The plugin permission call is a basic function with no callbacks:

```
window.FirebasePlugin.grantPermission();
```

I need to pause the app loading and only continue after the user has granted/declined the permissions request.  Below is my attempt to do so in the app init section of my app:

```
  function iosPush() {
    var q = $q.defer() ;
    if (/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
      window.FirebasePlugin.grantPermission(function(status) {
        q.resolve(status) ;
      },function(err) {errMgmt("ctrl/init",35,"iOS Push ask Permission error: "+err) });) ;
    } else {
      q.resolve("Android") ;
    }
    return q.promise ;
  }

    iosPush().then(function(status) {
      return getLocationAuth()
    }).then(function(status) {
      ...do other stuff...
    }) ;
```

my attempt to pause the app though is not working.  Can someone assist or point out how I can achieve the app init pause on requesting that iOS permission?

Lastly, no matter what the user selects, grants or denies permission, `status` is always `null`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I ended up using https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin to check the permission status. Pops up a Popup with a button. When user dismisses the permission dialog, he has to dismiss the popup by clicking on the button. Then I check the permission status again. It’s not a solution, it’s just a workaround. A bit ugly but works.

Have you found a solution yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I was close in my original question...had to modify it to the following:

```
  function iosPush() {
    var q = $q.defer() ;
    if (/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {  // 1st hasPerm
      window.FirebasePlugin.hasPermission(function(data){
        if (data.isEnabled == false) {
          window.FirebasePlugin.grantPermission(function(status) {  // if no, grant
            // Permission Granted or notGranted...need to check again.
            window.FirebasePlugin.hasPermission(function(data){  
            // 2nd hasPerm, if changed, set internal db 
              var oldPushEnabled = getDB('dev_pushEnabled') ;
              if (data.isEnabled == true) { 
                var pushIsEnabled = 1 ; 
              } else {
                var pushIsEnabled = 0 ;
              }
              if (oldPushEnabled != pushIsEnabled) {
                setDB('dev_pushEnabled',pushIsEnabled) ; // set local app db value
                q.resolve("PushStatusNotChanged") ;  // push enable status has changed
              } else {
                q.resolve("PushStatusChanged") ;  // push enable status has not changed
              }
            }) ;  // close 1st hasPermission
          },function(error) {
            // Permission NOT GRANTED
            q.resolve("PushNotGranted") ;
          }) ; // grantPermission
        } else {
          q.resolve("PushGranted") ;  // authorization was previously granted
        }
      }) ;  // close 2nd hasPermission
    } else {
      q.resolve("Android") ;
    }
    return q.promise ;
  }

  iosPush().then(function(status) {
     return getLocationAuth()
  }).then(function(status) {
    ...do other stuff...
  }) ;
```

In the function the double `hasPermission` acts as the grantPermission success/fail call back.  A bit of kludge, but it works like charm.